# Is speed control effect for a time range or just one specific strip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm using v2.79,when I add speed control to one single video strip,and it would affect audio strip within the time range of the video strip I select,so how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting audio and video from your clip to get two separate files. Next, in VSE, change only the extracted video strip speed.

Comment: thank you for your advice,that effect could be achieved in this way indeed,but the method is not "elegent" enough in my opinion,I wonder if there is an option inside blender to control this?And I followed the tutorial by Mikeycal Meyers on youtube,in his video,the speed control was just applied to the strip he selected